# What is an efficient way to connect Excel to ML.NET?

Tags: excel, dll, ml.net

Ultimately I would like to generate **ML.NET code** that can be consumed by **Excel**.  I would generally assume that creating a DLL would be the most appropriate way.  Having an **Excel VBA** wrapper around it would then allow non-programmers to utilize it via "=" cell functions.  I am rather surprised that Microsoft has not supplied that yet, but I am not finding anything along those lines.

I found a rather extensive approach here.  I would prefer something simpler if possible, but am willing to do that, if that is what it takes:

[How to call C functions from Excel using a DLL written in C (or C++)](https://sites.google.com/site/jrlhost/links/excelcdll)

I have also found references to Excel-DNA in this Q&A:

[Creating add-in for Excel using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020234/creating-add-in-for-excel-using-c-sharp)

Any incremental pointers towards that goal would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a way to do that, since ML.Net uses clr-Host. That means that Excel would have to start the clr runtime.
Excel allows to import statically linked c++ and c compiled Functions, since they dont require a runtime and are compiled to machine code.